# Clone RabbitMQ admin users, etc. on replacement server

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra, amqp

We have a couple of crusty AWS hosts running a RabbitMQ implementation in a cluster. We need to upgrade the hardware, and therefore we developed a Chef cookbook to spawn replacement servers.

One thing that we would rather not recreate by hand is the admin users, the queues, etc.

What is the best method to get that stuff from the old hosts to the new ones? I believe it's everything that lives in the `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` directory.

Is it wise to copy the files from one host to another?

Is there a programmatic means to do this?

Can it be coded into our Chef cookbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely export and import configuration via command line: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

I'm not sure about admin user,  though.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new rabbitmq nodes on your new hardware, you will get all the users in that new node. This is easy to try:

1. run docker container with image of rabbitmq (with management plugin)
   and create a user
2. run another container and add that node to the
   cluster of the first one
3. kill rabbitmq on the first one, or delete
   the docker container and you will see that you still have the newly
   created user on the 2nd (but now master) node

I wrote docker since it's faster to create a cluster this way, but if you already have a cluster you could use it for testing if you prefer.

For the queues and exchanges, I don't want to quote almost everything found in the rabbitmq doc page for the [high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html), but I will just say that you have to pay attention to the following:

- exclusive queues because they are gone once the client connection is gone
- queue mirroring (if you have any set up, if not it would be wise to consider it, if not even necessary)

I would do the migration gradually, waiting for the queues to get emptied and then kill of the nodes on the old hardware. It maybe doable in a big-bang fashion, but seems riskier. If you have a running system, than set up queue mirroring and try to find appropriate moment to do manual sync - but careful, this has a huge impact on the broker performance.

Additionally there is this [shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) (I have to point out that I did not use it or even explore it) but that may be another way to go since (quoting form the link):

> In essence, a shovel is a simple pump. Each shovel:
>
> connects to the source broker and the destination broker, consumes
>   messages from the queue, re-publishes each message to the destination
>   broker (using, by default, the original exchange name and
>   routing_key).